How to determine the completion of the AVSpeedSynthesizer.write() method?
I use the new method that writes a speech utterance to file:
func write(AVSpeechUtterance, toBufferCallback: AVSpeechSynthesizer.BufferCallback)

And judging whether the write has ended by whether the buffer length is 0.
synthesis.write(utterance) { (buffer) in
   guard let pcmBuffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
        log("unknow buffer type: \(buffer)")
         return
   }
   if pcmBuffer.frameLength == 0 {
       print("Finished")
       self.writeComplete()
   }
   else {
      self.writeToFile(buffer: pcmBuffer)
   }
}

It works well on iOS 16 and early,but on iOS 17(my device is 17.2.1), no pcmBuffer callback whose frameLength is 0,so i can not know write is complete,causing my writeComplete method never to be called.
Is there a better (or more accurate) way to determine write completion?
